# What is the significance of the term 'bread falling from the table '?

Tags: matthew, history, cultural-analysis

What is the historical background of the mention of 'bread falling from the table' as is seen in  Matthew 15:27 (NIV): “Yes it is, Lord,” she said. “Even the dogs eat the crumbs that fall from their master’s table.”

I have seen it claimed in some Bible TV serials that the rich people used to clean their fingers with an inferior kind of bread between one course of meal and another, and then throw those pieces of bread down. Is there any authentic reference to prove that such a practice existed at the time of Jesus?

Comment: You should go back up to verse 20. The woman was not a Jew. Non-Jew where call dogs before the cross

Answer (score 3):

Jesus tells a parable that is consistent with the practice:

> *And a certain poor man, Lazarus by name, had been put at his gate— having been covered-with-sores,  and desiring to be filled-to-satisfaction by the things falling (πιπτόντων) from the table of the rich man. Even indeed the dogs coming were licking his sores. (Luke 16:19-21 DLNT)*

The word **fell** (πιπτόντων) is the same word used in Matthew 15:27.

Jesus tells a parable using the same word "fell" (πιπτόντων). In that context, a poor man desires to be fed from that which fell from the table of the rich man.

In the parable, the word "crumbs" is added by many translations. The word actually used is τῶν which means "that" which includes a wide range. It could mean an inferior type of bread. It could also mean crumbs, leftovers, or food that did not measure up to the rich man's expectations. For example, in a restaurant a meal that does meet expectations is sent back and replaced. The rejected meal could be thrown out, or given to a homeless person outside.